# Disable field in the crud

Tags: laravel-backpack

I need to update a record, but I want to display some fields as disabled for editing. I don't want to let the user edit a certain field, but I want to display them

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your problem correctly then you may want to try something like this.

```
CRUD::addField([
            'name' => 'nameOfYourField',
            'label' => 'nameOFLabel',
            'type' => 'number',
            'attributes' => [
               'readonly' => 'readonly',
             ],
        ]);
```

You can also use 'disabled' => 'disabled', but it depends what you want exatly to achieve with the values.
Check it out [here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-fields#optional-field-attributes)